# Iterating over pandas dataframe with re.compile

Tags: python

I have this regex function to extract one of entity

```py
Entity_regex = re.compile(r'(Entity1:)(\s*)((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-/]*)(\s[A_Z]))' , re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
            match = re.search(Entity_regex, text)
            if match:
                Entity1 = match.group(3)
            else:
                Entity1 = 'NA'
```

This is working fine for an entity.

Similarly I have many entities to be extracted from a text file. I have made dataframe with Entity search word and their patter as two columns like below;

```py
Entity          Regex
Entity1:        (?:[a-zA-Z0-9-/]*)(\s[A_Z])
Entity2:        (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2} - \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} d{2}:\d{2})
```

I tried a for loop to iterate over the df using iterrows like this to create a final dataframe with all the entities from a text file

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Entity']=re.compile(r'(row['Entity'])(\s*)(row['Regex']') , re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    match = re.search(row['Entity'], text)
    if match:
        row['Entity'] = match.group(3)
    else:
        row['Entity'] = 'NA'
```

Getting ERROR like this:

```py
 row['Entity']=re.compile(r'(row['Entity'])(\s*)(row['Regex']') , re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says invalid syntax and does point you to the correct place.
If you look at the code carefully you will see that you have speechmarks in a string, which will end the string and cause a syntax error. You should use this line instead:

```py
row['Entity']=re.compile((r'({})(\s*)({})').format(row['Entity'],row['Regex']) , re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
```